# probelm with spphys bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing a paper in which I use:

```
\bibliographystyle{spphys}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

For instance for the reference:

```
@ARTICLE{Collett, author = {{Collett}, T.~E. and {Bacon}, D.},
        title = "{Testing the speed of gravitational waves over cosmological distances with strong gravitational lensing}",
      journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
       eprint = {1602.05882},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
     keywords = {Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena, Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology, High Energy Physics - Experiment},
         year = 2016,
        month = feb,
       adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016arXiv160205882C},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

the problem is that for the references which only have `arXiv` reference number, the only thing printed is:

[image]

What I want is the whole `arXiv` identifier to be printed.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You might want to consider the LaTeX Stack Exchange, since this isn't a programming question. They're also amazing experts on the matter.

Comment: What happens if you add an entry `issue={1602.05882}`?

Comment: @Walter It doesn't help :(